# Why i can't set the value to input range

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an music player. I have got an seekbar in the player but the problem is that that default value is not 0. When i try to set it to 0 it does not. Then i figured out it was happening because i changed the value of it with the progress of the music playing. When i comment it everything works fine . But i want the value to be 0 while having the progress indicator of the music.
This is the Input html=>

```
<input id="progressbar" class="w-96 mt-2 "  value="0"  type="range">
```

This is the js function which is affecting it

```
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', ()=> {
    progress =parseInt((audio.currentTime/audio.duration)* 100)
    progressbar.value = progress; //This is the line which is making problem
    
}
)
```

Please solve my problem if you can and thanks.

Comment: That `parseInt` is superfluous. Remove it. Other than that, please [edit] and provide a [mre].

Comment: @SebastianSimon OP might be using it instead of calling Math.floor() on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code (as @Sebastian Simon said).
The value param of an range input has some validations:

- If the value is set to something which can't be converted into a valid floating-point number, validation fails because the input is suffering from a bad input.
- The value won't be less than min. The default is 0.
- The value won't be greater than max. The default is 100.
- The value will be a multiple of step. The default is 1.

Source: MDN Web Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Please check if all criteria apply to your value.